# What's the value of sensor width for a default 3D View?

Tags: python, 3d-view, interface

I'd like to calculate FOV in degrees of the default 3D Viewport (not a camera). According to [this link](https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/how-to-get-camera-fov-in-degrees-from-focal-length-in-mm/) the formula requires me to provide sensor width and focal length. Focal length can be seen in the view tab:

[image]

I don't see the value of sensor width though. Where can I find it? Or perhaps is there a way to get a value in degrees on radians straight away (perhaps from the Python code...?)

**Edit**

To clarify furhter, the value I'm interested in should allow me to replicate what I'm seeing in the default 3D Viewport in a separate rendering engine. For example, with OpenGL one can create a perspective matrix using following code:

```
glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(FOV), (float)screen_width / (float)screen_width, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
```

How is 3D Viewport Focal Length translating to this `FOV` value? For a Viewport size equal to `2115x1180` sensor width seems to be equal to `40 mm` and I can generate a matching image of the default cube in OpenGL using the value of `43.60281897270362` (from `math.degrees(2 * math.atan(40 /(2 * 50)))`). If I resize Blender's 3D Viewport the cube generated in OpenGL and cube as seen in Blender no longer match. So what's a correct formula...?

For the reference, Viewport size can be obtained with

```
view = next(area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D')
window = next(view for view in view.regions if view.type == 'WINDOW')
(window.width, window.height)
```

**Edit**

To illustrate the problem further: if I resize my Blender Viewport to `1376x894` then to generate a matching image in OpenGL I need to pass down an angle of about `37.75`, meaning that for constant Focal Length equal to `50 mm` I have sensor width equal to about `34.19`. So given these three input parameters `(width=1376, height=894, focal_length=50)`, how do I obtain this output value of `34.19`?

Comment: The view tab corresponds to the viewport's "camera" used to view the scene (not a real camera object).  Click on your camera object and check the green camera button in the bottom right pane.

Comment: Sensor width is in the camera properties (Properties Panel > Object Data / Camera Icon > Camera > Sensor Size). The 3D viewport doesn't have this value though. It seems that the stock camera has a sensor width of 36mm.

Comment: Please see my edited question. I don't care about cameras, what I want to achieve is replicating of what I'm seeing on Viewport with OpenGL and I'm not sure how to obtain the FOV value to calculate my perspective matrix depending on Viewport resolution.

Comment: I think you may have to calculate that yourself, my intuition is that it's not exposed to the API. you may find interesting things there https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/250935/86891 on rapid inspection the [window_matrix](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RegionView3D.html#bpy.types.RegionView3D.window_matrix) prop seems to update when the area is resized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula that works for me:

```cpp
min(width, height)/max(width, height) * 72
```

My C++ code is looking like this:

```cpp
float Renderer::calculate_fov(uint16_t width, uint16_t height) {
    float aspect_inverted = static_cast<float>(std::min(width, height)) / static_cast<float>(std::max(width, height));
    // 72 is a default value for 1:1 aspect ratio in Blender
    float sensor_width = 72 * aspect_inverted;
    float focal_length = 50;
    return 2 * atan(sensor_width/(2*focal_length));
}

void Renderer::init(uint16_t width, uint16_t height) {
    // ...
    glm::mat4 projection_matrix = glm::perspective(
        calculate_fov(width, height),
        float(width)/float(height),
        0.1f,
        1000.0f
    );

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/19532463/1542900
    // view = next(area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D')
    // look_at = view.spaces[0].region_3d.view_location
    // location = self.camera_position(view.spaces[0].region_3d.view_matrix)
    // up = view.spaces[0].region_3d.view_rotation @ mathutils.Vector((0.0, 1.0, 0.0))
    glm::mat4 view_matrix = glm::lookAt(location, look_at, up);

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to source, default sensor size is 36x24:

https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/makesdna/DNA_camera_types.h#L173

Width is used to calculation viewport camera:

https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/editors/space_view3d/view3d_utils.c#L1188

Comment: Interesting! But you can easily see that resizing the viewport is somehow affecting this value (you can see the default cube getting smaller to fit nicely in reduced space). I'm trying to figure out either what's the final result or how to disable this effect.

Comment: Well, Blender takes the biggest side of viewport (width or height) for calculation