# In camera view, how do you zoom past the point where blender stops zooming?

Tags: 3d-view, navigation

How do you zoom past the point where blender stops zooming and still stay in orthogonal mode?
I'd like to avoid using `.`, as it switches to perspective.

I tried all [these](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point/651#651) approaches, but it switches the camera to perspective.

[image]

I'd like to avoid the following switch to perspective mode, like this:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know how to force Blender to stop zooming in, but when I just zoom in on something for example in _Top Orthographic_ view, pressing `Numpad .` actually does not switch to _Perspective_ on my PC. Is it only when Blender stopped zooming?

Comment: Just saw something - that's not the orthographic view of the _3D Viewport_, it is a camera set to _Orthographic_. Well, that's different, because focusing on an object then takes you out of the camera view. It is very inconvenient to stay in camera view for modeling when you want to zoom in and out of the object. To do this in camera view would only make sense if you would want to zoom in and preserve the perspective - which you do not have with an orthographic camera anyway. So why not use the viewport instead of the camera? Then Blender would not switch between perspective and orthographic.

Comment: I use BlenderBIM, that uses cameras as various drawings (floor plans, sections, elevations, etc.).  As a workflow, i constantly switch between these various drawings, as I work.  As such, it's just more efficient, if I could just stay in this 'camera' mode verses switching out to viewport, every time I have to really zoom into something.

Comment: BlenderBIM is a third-party addon and I have no idea how it works. I don't even really understand what "uses cameras as various drawings" means. Therefore I can't tell if there is no better way with collections, view layers or whatever to achieve similar efficiency. So, if you have to keep up using the camera view, I guess there is no other chance than using `Numpad .` and `Numpad 5` directly afterwards to immediately switch back to _Orthographic_ view. In the _Preferences_ you can disable automatic switching to _Perspective_ when rotating the view, but that does not work with cameras.

Comment: FWIW I think you're mistaking camera view and orthogonal view. A camera view (Numpad 0) can be orthogonal or perspective. Pressing Numpad . gets you out of camera view, whether it is orthogonal or perspective is irrelevant to your problem

Answer (score 1):

It seems this value is (arbitrarily) hardcoded to 600.

[See the relevant docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RegionView3D.html#bpy.types.RegionView3D.view_camera_zoom)

You can test this out using the snippet from [another answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/250935/86891).

```
import bpy

zoom = 5
screen = bpy.context.screen
area = next(area for area in screen.areas if area.type == "VIEW_3D")
space = area.spaces.active
region_3d = space.region_3d
region_3d.view_camera_zoom += zoom
```

It is not uncommon for Blender devs to change hard limits. For example the [bevel segment limit](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/bevel-hard-limit-needed/23103/4) has been set to a soft-cap in the past. A thread over on Right Click Select or devtalk to explain the problem might help solving it, usually for these kind of changes it's just a matter of changing a few variables in the property definitions.